# Updating products with Magmi

Tags: magento-1.8, product, magmi

I'm using Magmi version: 0.7.18  to update price of products. While the initial import of the products was successful, updating the price of the some products is not reflected in the backend.

Do i need to reindex  catalog_product_price ? or reindex all ?